# How can I run Entity Framework commands outside Package Manager Console?

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, powershell

I'm familiar with using Entity Framework commands in Package Manager Console within Visual Studio e.g.

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=Blah;Database=Blah;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

I'd like to do the same in an external PowerShell script as part of an automation routine. How would I go about importing Entity Framework tools for use outside of Visual Studio?

Comment: "dotnet ef" perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you check out this resource as an introduction into using EF Core with existing databases:

http://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/walkthroughs/existing-database

You can find an example in the middle for using the command line:

```
 dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=.\;Database=AdventureWorksLT2012;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Model
```

Regarding the `-o` option:

> The -o option (or alternatively --output-dir) specifies the directory
>   where the class files will be generated. If it is omitted, the class
>   files will be generated in the project directory (where the .csproj
>   file is located).